# How to add a break point in Intelij IDEA to debug Rust code

Tags: intellij-idea, rust

I have installed Intellij IDEA on ubuntu with Rust plugin.
How to add a break point in Intellij IDEA to debut RUST code.
Do I need any additional plugin?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8182-rust/docs/rust-debugging.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need for extra plugins just add them like you would do in java (left click right of the number). but in order to debug (apply them) you'll need [Native Debugging Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12775-native-debugging-support) (i believe the ide autosuggests this plugin on the first debug run)

Comment: But how to add Break point? As the context menu does not show any option to add a breakpoint

Answer (score 5):

Debugging Rust code is available in CLion, IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, PyCharm Professional, and GoLand. For IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, PyCharm Pro, GoLand it is required to install the [Native Debugging Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12775-native-debugging-support)
 plugin.

See plugin's documentation for more information: [Debugging﻿](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8182-rust/docs/rust-debugging.html).